# Get fixed ID of NFC chip in Android

Tags: android, nfc, hce

As my title, I have a SS Note. When it communicate with a NFC Reader, it generate a fixed ID
How can I get it in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: You can't. Android does not provide an API to retrieve the anti-collision identifier.

---

However, it really depends on what component generates the fixed ID:

- NFC controller (unlikely if the ID is fixed): In that case, it's likely that there is no option to retrieve the ID from software.
- Android NFC stack on the application processor (though a very unlikely case): If you have access to the Android source and can compile your custom Android system, you could try to hack something into the system that you could use to retrive the ID.
- Secure Element (e.g. a SIM card or an embedded SE): If you can install applets to that SE (again, a very unlikely case) **and** the SE has an API to expose it's anti-collision identifier to applets **and** you have access to that SE from the application processor (e.g. through Open Mobile API), you could query that applet for the ID.