# Android NFC card emulation

Tags: android, nfc, smartcard-reader, serial-number, hce

I would like to use NFC on Android for card emulation. When I put the device on a Mifare reader I get the card number. Is it possible to change this card number programatically in my device?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't set the anti-collision identifier (UID, this is what MIFARE readers typically display as the "card number") programmatically in Android. Actually, by default, many Android devices will expose a random UID (see [Get Static NFC Tag Id with HCE mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27239473/2425802) and [Get fixed ID of NFC chip in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27011889/2425802)).

However, at least for the Broadcom NFC chipset it seems to be possible to set the anti-collision identifer to a static value by either editing a configuration file on the system image ([Editing Functionality of Host Card Emulation in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28409934/2425802)) or by customizing the libnfc-nci ([Host-based Card Emulation with Fixed Card ID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28360190/2425802))